# What is the default size of a varchar2 input to Oracle stored procedure, and can it be changed?

Tags: oracle, stored-procedures, varchar2

I have a stored procedure in Oracle Database 10g where my input is a varchar2 but I'm having issues getting it to run when the input string is long (not sure of exact length maybe > 8000).

My thought is the 'intext varchar2' (as below) is by default is too small.  In other cases where I need a longer string I might define a varchar2 as "intext2 VARCHAR2(32767);" I tried to define the size similarly in the code below but my syntax is incorrect.

```
create or replace PROCEDURE TESTPROC ( intext IN VARCHAR2

) AS ....
```

What is the (default) size of the intext varchar2?

Can that size be defined (increased)?

Answer (score 42, accepted):

You cannot specify a size for a VARCHAR2 parameter to a procedure.

The procedure should happily accept strings up to 32k in size (the maximum size of a VARCHAR2 in PL/SQL).  If it were a function that was being called from SQL rather than PL/SQL, the limit would be 4k because the maximum size of a VARCHAR2 in SQL is only 4k.

Comment: Justin is this statement true for output parameter also?

Comment: @D.J. - `out` parameters also do not specify a size, yes.

Comment: But in my case its failing is there any settings that controls parameter size?

Comment: @D.J. - Can you define "failing"?  Since the caller needs to declare a variable to hold the output and that variable has to have a size, it is entirely possible that the procedure is trying to return a string that is larger than the variable the caller has declared.  If so, the caller would need to declare a larger variable.  You still wouldn't declare a length for the procedure's `out` parameter

Comment: create or replace PROCEDURE USP_TEST(V_OUTPUT  OUT VARCHAR2)IS
VAR_PLSQL VARCHAR2(32000);
TEMP        NUMBER;
BEGIN
     FOR REC IN 1..4005 LOOP
                      BEGIN
                            VAR_PLSQL := VAR_PLSQL||', '||REC;
                      END;
                      END LOOP;
SELECT  VSIZE(VAR_PLSQL)  INTO TEMP FROM DUAL;
DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE(TEMP);
   V_OUTPUT := VAR_PLSQL;
END;

Comment: this test procedure will fail at line 12 for me where i am assigning a pl/sql variable to parameter

Comment: @D.J. - That procedure works fine if the caller declares a large enough variable to receive the output.  The procedure will encounter an error if the caller declares a variable that is too small.  The procedure is fine.  The issue is in the caller.  See for example https://livesql.oracle.com/apex/livesql/s/iey4rah32k89uasixt32i9al1

Comment: I am simply running this from sql developer

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/193652/discussion-between-justin-cave-and-d-j).