# How to get rid of empty but huge LOB column?

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle11g

We've got a table with a LOB column which is empty as the content has be transfered to some other  place (another column). However, the LOB segment still occupies 300 GB, and I cannot get rid of it.

Here is a minimal example:

```
CREATE TABLE t (id NUMBER, c CLOB) 
  LOB (c) STORE AS BASICFILE (DISABLE STORAGE IN ROW RETENTION NONE);
INSERT INTO t SELECT object_id, object_name FROM all_objects;
COMMIT;

UPDATE T SET c=NULL;
COMMIT;
```

Now, the LOB is empty, but the storage still occupies 500 MB:

```
SELECT s.bytes/1024/1024 as mb 
  FROM user_lobs 
  JOIN dba_segments s using (segment_name);

MB
528
```

In the minimal example, `ALTER TABLE xxx MOVE` works, but not with the real table, as it is too big and runs into various Oracle errors. Online redefinition doesn't work, too, as the underlying datatype is BINARY XML. Expdp/impdp takes too long for production.

I simply can't believe that it is not possible to reclaim the space of a totaly empty column.

Who can help, please?

Comment: Drop the column?

Comment: @Littlefoot: Good idea, I'm testing this right now. Need to re-add the column to avoid changing application code.

Comment: I'm going to sleep; will see the result tomorrow morning. Good luck!

Comment: @Littlefoot: Seems to work, in the `ALTER TABLE ... SET UNUSED; ALTER TABLE DROP UNUSED COLUMNS;` version. Many thanks! How do we get this into an acceptable answer?

Comment: To the person flagging this as close: No, this is not a DBA question. A DBA would never suggest to drop a column as @Littlefoot did. It is not in their remit to change the data model, so they wouldn't think of simply dropping a column...

Comment: Good, I'm glad you did it. Don't worry about the *acceptable answer*, I just suggested it, but it is you who did the whole job so - if you want - post your own answer with steps you took and accept it.

Answer (score 1):

As an alternative to dropping and re-adding the column you could use [the `shrink space` clause](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e41084/statements_3001.htm#i2192484):

```
ALTER TABLE t MODIFY LOB (c) (SHRINK SPACE);
```

[db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=9ee4cedaf71f57f658ad31a9fcb4c124), which is 18c but ought to work in 11g too. (Later: yes, it does in 11gR2 with `retention none` omitted anyway; SQL Fiddle doesn't like it though.)

> the underlying datatype is BINARY XML

Missed that detail, but it still works; you just need an extra step to find the hidden BLOB column backing up the XMLType column, [as shown here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24887830/266304). I've made the `alter` dynamic just to pick that up on the fly, but if you can find it manually then you can just plug it into the statement yourself obviously:

```
DECLARE
  l_name USER_TAB_COLUMNS.COLUMN_NAME%TYPE;
  l_stmt VARCHAR2(100);
BEGIN
  select column_name
  into l_name
  from user_tab_cols 
  where 
    table_name = 'T' and hidden_column = 'YES'
    and
    column_id = (
        select column_id 
        from user_tab_cols 
        where table_name = 'T' and column_name = 'X'
    );

  l_stmt := 'ALTER TABLE t MODIFY LOB ("' || l_name || '") (SHRINK SPACE)';
  dbms_output.put_line(l_stmt);
  execute immediate l_stmt;
END;
/
```

[db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=e1e1dddb69805c7ada8f2bcf498ef6d9)

Probably worth noting that this works with `basicfile` storage, as shown in your minimal demo, but might not work with `securefile` storage - at least some of the time that throws ORA-10635: Invalid segment or tablespace type.